# Sets and Logic .. Disproving with counter example

Tags: logic, examples-counterexamples

Can anyone please give me an idea to disprove the following with a counterexample:

$A , B , C$ are sets. If $A \times C = B \times C$ , then $A = B$. (Here $\times$ is a Cartesian product.)

I tried giving random numbers in Venn diagram, but that didn't work. And, using subset way to prove equal, I still couldn't solve it.

Comment: Can C be empty?

Comment: Thanks. I tried this . Is this the correct way?

Comment: suppose , A = {1,2} and B = {3,4} then AXC and AXB gives empty set as C is empty set because can't make any ordered pairs. but A is not equal to B or not a subset hence different elements.

Answer (score 2):

In cases like this,  you need to look at the extreme ends.   Here's a hint:  Pretend like it was multiplication.  Find numbers to disprove if $a\cdot c=b\cdot c$ then a=b.  What would make that equation fail?  Put that into set theory.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this way taking C as an empty set. Suppose , A = {1,2} and B = {3,4} then AXC and AXB gives empty set as C is empty set because can't make any ordered pairs. but A is not equal to B or not a subset hence different elements.

Comment: Correct! Generally degenerate caces lead to counterexamples, so its always a good place to start

Comment: This way my first post of my first year study .. so glad to get instant help from you both. Really Appreciate!!